# How to get extension and temp path in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a file upload function in laravel. The user gets to select multiple files so I need to separate the images file and the documents so I could compress the images. Therefore I need to get the extensions but it just doesn't work for me. I'm using Laravel 7.3 and these are the codes I tried:

`$request->files->getClientOriginalExtension();`

`$request->files->extension();`

I also tried to get the temp path using:

`$request->files->getPathName()`

This is the array returned by `$request->files`:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                        (
                            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Annotation 2020-02-26 084917.png
                            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/png
                            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6AA9.tmp
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php6AA9.tmp
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I also want to get the value from `[pathName:SplFileInfo:private]` so I could compress the image but all the codes I stated that I tried above return the same error:

> message: "Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag::getClientOriginalExtension()"

Edit:

I also tried

```
foreach($request->files as $file) {
   foreach ($file as $in) {
    print_r($in->extension());
   }
}
```

But would give an error `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::extension()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$request->files` is `array` of `files` so you have to `loop` through the `files array` to get the required result:

```
foreach($request->files as $file)
{
   echo $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   echo $file->getPathName();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error ```Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::extension()``` I modified the code a bit since it was an array within an array, so I used two foreach loops. I've added it in the changes above

Comment: Try this     `print_r($in->getClientOriginalExtension());`